# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue happens when using Core Data: '.Friend.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, preprocessor, lexical

I am writing functions of iOS Core Data. I have one `Entity` named `"Friend"`, its `Codegen` is `Category/Extension`. I have written my own Friend subclass as `NSManagedObject`. I am facing an issue that `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue`, `'.Friend.h' file not found` in file `Friend_CoreDataProperties.h` which is auto generated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After I manually correct `.Friend.h` to `Friend.h`, there will be another similar issue happening: `.Friend+CoreDataProperties.h not found` in file `CoreDataTest+CoreDataModel.h`

[image]

I can manually correct it as well, and it will build through and work fine. But each time the program is cleaned and rebuilt, the issue will comes out again because these code are automatically generated.

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After recreating another Core Data App, I found out that the `Current Product Module` is avoiding human generation and placing that dot before that h file importing line. Once I delete the `Current Product Module`, everything goes fine!

I have no idea why this happens, and how to deal with this problem in a correct way. Anyone who has the knowledge about this please help.